# Почему никогда не отрабатывает v-else?

Tags: vue.js

У меня есть 2 input`a: логин и пароль.
При вводе корректного логина и пароля отображается "Добро пожаловать".
Если некорректный ввод: "Ошибка входа" (v-else)

Проблема с некорректным вводом: v-else никогда не обрабатывается...
Не могу понять почему...

Остальное - работает так, как надо.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>IF-ELSE: Задание 2 (1 балл)</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <input type="text" name="login" v-model="login" placeholder="Введи логин">
        <input type="text" name="password" v-model="password" placeholder="Введи пароль">
        <div v-if="login && password">
            <p v-if="(login === 'toma') && (password === '123')"><b>Добро пожаловать</b></p>
            <p v-else-if="(login === 'petya') && (password === '777')"><b>Добро пожаловать</b></p>
            <p v-else-if="(login === 'olya') && (password === '456')"><b>Добро пожаловать<b></p>
            <p v-else><b>Ошибка входа</b></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

index.js

```
const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        login: '',
        password: '',
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы тег `<b>` предпоследний не закрыли. Всё у вас работает.
Пользуйтесь современными средствами разработки. Такие ошибки должен отслеживать редактор.

```js
const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        login: '',
        password: '',
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" name="login" v-model="login" placeholder="Введи логин">
  <input type="text" name="password" v-model="password" placeholder="Введи пароль">
  <div v-if="login && password">
    <p v-if="(login === 'toma') && (password === '123')"><b>Добро пожаловать</b></p>
    <p v-else-if="(login === 'petya') && (password === '777')"><b>Добро пожаловать</b></p>
    <p v-else-if="(login === 'olya') && (password === '456')"><b>Добро пожаловать</b></p>
    <p v-else><b>Ошибка входа</b></p>
  </div>
</div>
```